# Java ArrayList of Map - All Map objects are dupe

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist

I have a Map object whose values are constantly changing every time the map is updated.  They keys are always the same, but the values change.  Every time I change the Map object, I add it to an ArrayList.  I can see that the values in the map are different each time the new map is added to the ArrayList, but when the ArrayList finishes being updated and is ready to be read from, all the Map's in it are the same.

Can anyone think of why this might be?

This is basically all that is happening...UpdateLog gets called with a new Map about 20 times and each dataMap1 object is different.  It is added to the ArrayList.  When I debug, I can see dataMap1 values are different each time.  But when it is finished, every dataMap1 object in mapLog is the same!!

```
public void UpdateLog(final Map<String,String> dataMap1)
```

{

```
mapLog.add(dataMap1);
```

}

Answer (score 5):

You *claim* each dataMap1 object is different... but don't forget that the value of `dataMap1` is just a reference, not an object. If you're doing this:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

map.put("a", "b");
UpdateLog(map);

map.clear();
map.put("x", "y");
UpdateLog(map);
```

then that's not *actually* using two different objects. Make sure you've really got a different object each time:

```
// Replaces the call to map.clear()
map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("x", "y");
UpdateLog(map);
```

If this doesn't help, please post more code. Given your description though, this is what's happening. You may want to *copy* your map instead of creating a new map each time, of course.

Comment: Skeet is going to publish a book of all his SO answers and retire.  Then we can finally get some reputation.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - the thing is, the thread that updates dataMap nulls it out every time...while (!stop && serviceCn.isRunning()) { MyService svc = myServiceConn.getService(); Map<String,String> dataMap = null; dataMap = svc.getDataMap(); UpdateLog(dataMap) }

Comment: @Jesse: Setting it to null is pointless when you're about to assign the variable based on a call to `svc.getDataMap()` in the following statement. My guess is that `svc.getDataMap()` is returning a reference to the same map every time. That's what you need to look into.

Comment: sorry i just joined stackoverflow and when i try to add a comment i dont know how to designate it as code block and when i hit enter it just adds the comment :/

Comment: @Jesse: Just include it in backticks, so backtick x backtick becomes `x`.

Comment: @JonSkeet - backticks?  How can I efficiently make a new copy every time I send the object to UpdateLog

Comment: Wouldnt this work too - public void UpdateLog(final Map<String,String> dataMap1)
{

    Map<String,String> newMap = new HashMap<String,String>
    newMap = dataMap1;
    mapLog.add(newMap);    

}

Comment: @Jesse: No it wouldn't. It would just create an instance of `HashMap` and immediately ignore it. I suggest you set aside your current real task, and get hold of a good introductory Java book. You *really* need to understand how variables, objects and references work if you're going to get anything done reliably.

Comment: okay thanks, definitely different from c# which is what im used to...test `mycode okay i got it`

Comment: @Jesse: No, this isn't different from C# at all. You'd get *exactly* the same behaviour in C# using a `Dictionary<string, string>` if you called a method which always returned a reference to the same underlying dictionary.

Comment: okay that makes sense...the issue is that i cannot see the code from the service so i wasnt able to figure it was a ref issue...now i know so I will just have to make a copy to do what I need to do.

Comment: A simple Shallow Copy did the trick, now it has a unique map for every arraylist item `public void UpdateLog(final Map<String,String> dataMap1) { int index = mapLog.size()+1; Map<String,String> newMap = new HashMap<String,String>(dataMap1); final SingleFrame newFrame = new SingleFrame(index,1,0, dataMap1); mapLog.add(newFrame); }`